# Strange printf equation

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I have 2 pointers to some Point structures. I wanted to calculate distance between 2 points (i dont need to calculate root of it) so i have this:

```
    w[0]=X[l];
    w[1]=X[l+1];
    d=m(w[0]->x-w[1]->x)+m(w[0]->y-w[1]->y);
    printf("--TEST %d %d %d\n",w[0]->x,w[1]->x,w[0]->x-w[1]->x);
```

Input: X[l] = (0,1), X[l+1] = (2,0)
Output: --TEST 0 2 -1

Why is that?
Edit:

---

This was part of function find which finds 2 points with the smallest distance between them. In the main i have this:

```
X=(Punkt**)malloc(sizeof(Punkt*)*n);
Y=(Punkt*)malloc(sizeof(Punkt)*n);
int x,y;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i) {
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    Y[i].x=x;
    Y[i].y=y;
    X[i]=(Punkt*)malloc(sizeof(Punkt*));
    X[i]=&Y[i];
}
Quicksort(X,0,n-1);
Punkt **wynik=find(0,n-1);
printf("%d %d\n%d %d",wynik[0]->x,wynik[0]->y,wynik[1]->x,wynik[1]->y);
```

I've checked Quicksort, it works as it should. Function m: #define m(a) ((a)*(a))
 Only find function have bug in that part. This works, but i dont want to make variables for each coordinate.

```
int trash1=w[0]->x;
int trash2=w[1]->x;
printf("--TEST %d %d %d\n",w[0]->x,w[1]->x,w[0]->x-w[1]->x,trash1-trash2);
```

Input: 2 points (0,1) (2,0)
Output: --TEST 0 2 -1 -2

Comment: Can you provide some more context?  Where are `w` and `X` defined?  How do you know that the values in the array are what you think they are?

Comment: My guess is: **Undefined Behavior**! If you supply the types in question and use a bit more space in your code it might be easier to spot.

Comment: Learn to use whitespace (and better variable names), please.

Comment: Can you show us the `m` function and also show us that you are not changing your passed in variables in any way?

Comment: you got a typo : `printf("--TEST %d %d %d\n",w[0]->x,w[1]->x,w[0]->x-w[1]->x,trash1-trash2);` you have 3 format specifiers and you are printing four values

Comment: Show us the definition of `w`. BTW, why do you override `X[i]`?

Comment: My bad, i was rewriting from program not copying. It shows bad with "%d %d %d %d".

Comment: Where do i override X[i]?
Punkt **w=(Punkt**)malloc(sizeof(Punkt*)*2);

Comment: Here: `X[i]=(Punkt*)malloc(sizeof(Punkt*)); X[i]=&Y[i];`. Really? `Punkt w`?

Comment: I dunno why * and * didn't appeared after Punkt.

Comment: The malloc in the for loop is a leak. First you malloc then you "loose" that malloc by changing it to `&Y[i]`. The malloc is not needed as you already have mallocd `Y` before the `Y` loop.

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki could provide the definition for struct Punkt

Comment: Please provide the complete code for the smallest possible example which demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to reproduce what you experience. Using this I get `0 - 2 = - 2` as result:
(*In other words, not able to reproduce.*)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define m(a) ((a)*(a))

typedef struct pkt {
    int x;
    int y;
} Punkt;

int main(void)
{
    Punkt **X;
    Punkt  *Y;
    Punkt  *w[2];
    int x, y;
    int n = 2;
    int i;

    X = malloc(sizeof(Punkt*) * n);
    Y = malloc(sizeof(Punkt) * n);

    printf("Enter 2 integer point pairs: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        Y[i].x = x;
        Y[i].y = y;
        X[i] = &Y[i];
    }

    i = 0;
    w[0] = X[i];
    w[1] = X[i + 1];
    i = m(w[0]->x - w[1]->x) + m(w[0]->y - w[1]->y);

    printf("D: m(%d - %d) + m(%d - %d) = "
           "%d + %d = "
           "%d\n",
             w[0]->x,  w[1]->x,    w[0]->y,  w[1]->y,
           m(w[0]->x - w[1]->x), m(w[0]->y - w[1]->y),
           i);

    printf("TEST: %d - %d = %d\n",
            w[0]->x,
            w[1]->x,
            w[0]->x - w[1]->x);

    free(X);
    free(Y);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample:

```
$ ./pq
Enter 2 integer point pairs: 0 1 2 0
D: m(0 - 2) + m(1 - 0) = 4 + 1 = 5
TEST: 0 - 2 = -2
```